# Gdb debugger not working with R on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gdb, ubuntu-22.04

I'm using gdb on Ubuntu 22.04 to debug R code relying on a C++ source files. Untill I was working with Ubuntu 18.04 everything worked fine. Some months ago I updated my OS to Ubuntu 22.04 and since then gdb doesn't allow me to debug R code anymore.

Specifically when I run on terminal the command

`R -d gdb`

I get simply a segmentation fault

[Segmentation fault when calling gdb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Svf.png)

gdb itself seems to work fine out of R

[Calling gdb only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saOr6.png)

I have no idea why I observe this behaviour. I already tried to purge gdb and reinstalling it back, but I got the same result.

Does anybody have an idea of what is going on?

I ran the commands

```
gdb -ex 'set env LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/R/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server' \
  -ex "set height 0" -ex run -ex where \
  -ex "info shared" --args \
gdb /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R
```

As result I get this:

```
/u/sw/pkgs/toolchains/gcc-glibc/9/base/share/gdb/python/gdb/command/prompt.py:48: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if self.value is not '':
/u/sw/pkgs/toolchains/gcc-glibc/9/base/share/gdb/python/gdb/command/prompt.py:60: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if self.value is not '':
GNU gdb (mk) 8.3.1
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-mk-linux".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://github.com/elauksap/mk/issues>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from gdb...
(No debugging symbols found in gdb)
Starting program: /u/sw/pkgs/toolchains/gcc-glibc/9/base/bin/gdb /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000003 in ?? ()
#0  0x0000000000000003 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff7253bb9 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00007ffff7fd6090  0x00007ffff7ff3e40  Yes (*)     /u/sw/pkgs/toolchains/gcc-glibc/9/prefix/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x00007ffff7f8e800  0x00007ffff7fb1645  No          /u/sw/pkgs/toolchains/gcc-glibc/9/base/lib/libreadline.so.7
0x00007ffff7f5d280  0x00007ffff7f6dc14  No          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
0x00007ffff7f28090  0x00007ffff7f4f61a  No          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6
0x00007ffff7f1b040  0x00007ffff7f1b105  No          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
0x00007ffff7bff7b0  0x00007ffff7dcc3ff  No          /u/sw/pkgs/toolchains/gcc-glibc/9/base/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
0x00007ffff7b58040  0x00007ffff7b6b97b  No          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1
0x00007ffff7b50040  0x00007ffff7b50105  No          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
0x00007ffff7b4b040  0x00007ffff7b4b105  No          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1
0x00007ffff7a713a0  0x00007ffff7aec8e8  No          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
0x00007ffff7a36290  0x00007ffff7a545a7  No          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
0x00007ffff7a0a3c0  0x00007ffff7a240de  No          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5
0x00007ffff7922170  0x00007ffff793616f  No          /u/sw/pkgs/toolchains/gcc-glibc/9/base/lib/libiconv.so.2
0x00007ffff767ae00  0x00007ffff770a76a  No          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpfr.so.6
0x00007ffff75f6440  0x00007ffff765454d  No          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10
0x00007ffff7464440  0x00007ffff756bb02  No          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
0x00007ffff73a5660  0x00007ffff73bbbe5  No          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
0x00007ffff71a2700  0x00007ffff7334abd  No          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
0x00007ffff7156700  0x00007ffff716601b  No          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your first step should be to find the `core` dump and figure out A) which binary actually crashes (could be `R`, could be `gdb`) and B) _where_ did it crash.

Comment: I've updated the answer -- there are a few more command-line arguments needed for further analysis. P.S. Please don't link to pictures of text. Cut/paste the text into your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like running `R -d gdb` performs the following:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/R/lib:\
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server \
gdb /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R
```

and GDB doesn't like something about that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

So step 0 is to run above command in a shell and confirm that it causes GDB to crash.

Step 1 is to run

```
gdb -ex 'set env LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/R/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server' \
  -ex "set height 0" -ex run -ex where \
  -ex "info shared" --args \
gdb /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R
```

and edit the question with the output.